# ffmpeg problem in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

i am using iFrameExtractor [URL](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone/comment-page-1#comment-1116) (which uses FFMPEG) for creating FFMPEG client.how can i send those images to server in which FFMPEG configured?
in which format i have to send to server?any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn’t use FFmpeg to do this anymore. The [AVFoundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) supports frame extraction and is hardware accelerated, so that you should get higher performance. There is a very nice video about AVFoundation in the WWDC resources.

Comment: it converts video as images ..i agree...but if we send images to server,we can convert it as video again.but NO AUDIO WILL BE THERE.FFMPEG will give AVPICTURE which will give audio.